# sql query to select and update

Tags: sql

I saw the below query in algoexpert where they say they can update the job id based on the previous query. I have seen an update query with a select clause inside it or the merge clause that inserts or updates depending on a match

Is there some SQL syntax that lets you do the below. Please can you point me to links to read up on this?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  SELECT * FROM jobs_table WHERE status = 'QUEUED' ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1;
  // if there's none, we ROLLBACK;
  UPDATE jobs_table SET status = 'RUNNING' WHERE id = id from previous query;
  COMMIT;
```

Comment: Have you tried `where id in (...)`

Comment: Specify which dbms you are using

Comment: You could use `UPDATE jobs_table SET ... WHERE EXISTS(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE jobs_table 
SET status = 'RUNNING' 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM jobs_table 
             WHERE status = 'QUEUED' 
             ORDER BY created_at ASC 
             LIMIT 1);
```

When no `id` is found in the sub-query, nothing is being updated.